# Problem with INSTALLED_APPS in django settings.py file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-apps

If I try to add blog.apps.BlogConfig string to INSTALLED_APPS (to define the blog app), local server won't start giving me an error. Photos attached below:[image: Terminal when launching local server]
[image: Defining app in Sublime Text]

I am expecting for the separate section to appear on site.
Was doing it by tutorial of the Youtuber Corey Schafer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDwdMDQ8oX4&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03T

Comment: You are missing a comma at the end of the first entry in `INSTALLED_APPS`. `'blog.apps.BlogConfig',`. Also, don't post screenshots of code. Post the code itself.

Answer (score -1):

It's so simple.

Just put your application name in INSTALLED_APPS list.

Like, if you have application name "blog", then just put ...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog',
    ...
]
```

That's it !

Still, if you need to put name of your application in INSTALLED_APPS list as "blog.apps.BlogConfig", then just go to apps.py in your application, and put ...

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'
```

Thanks !